# VB.NET split int64 to two 32bit strings, and reverse

Tags: vb.net

I have a 64 bit integer that needs the bit value stored as two 32bit strings into a database where it is read by a 3rd party system, and then I need to convert it back. This needs done in VB.NET as it's part of an already established large project.  I've tried searching for examples but haven't found anything that makes sense for VB.NET, mostly C++, PHP or Java examples out there.

My code needs to run in the following manor.  I know I'm not using the << and >> right, I think there is supposed to be something like And &HFFFFFFFF mixed in there, but I'm not clear on how exactly this process is done.

```
Sub StoreValue()
            Dim int64Value As Int64
            Dim str32Value As String
            Dim str64Value As String

            int64Value = txtRawNumericValue.text

            If int64Value > 4294967295 Then
                '<Code broken>
                'store first 32 bits of value as string
                str32Value = int64Value << 32
                'store 2nd 32 bits of value as string
                str64Value = int64Value >> 32
                '</Code broken>

                'Store and Use variables here
            Else
                str32Value = int64Value.ToString
            End If
End Sub

Function RetrieveValue() As Int64 
            Dim int64Value As Int64
            Dim str32Value As String = StoredValue32
            Dim str64Value As String = StoredValue64

            If str64Value <> "" then
                '<Code broken>
                'Combine 2 values back into 64bit Integer
                int64Value = str64Value & str32Value  
                '</Code broken>

                Return int64Value 
            Else
                Return str32Value 
            End If 

End Function
```

Comment: Are you sure you need "32 bit strings," and what are 32 bit strings?

Comment: Is the data supposed to be big- or little-endian?

Comment: According to the 3rd party vendor, This is what I have.

Lower-Limit is the lower 32 bits (4 bytes) of the total limit.
Upper-Limit-Gigawords is the upper 32 bits (4 bytes) of the total limit.

Total-Limit = Lower-Limit + (Upper-Limit-Gigawords << 32)

Upper-Limit-Gigawords 4G (2^32) bytes of total limit (bits 32..63, when bits 0..31 are delivered in Lower-Limit)

Both values are stored in SQL using the datatype nchar256 and cannot be larger than 4294967295

Comment: So they want string representations of the two dwords of the qword, unsigned?

Comment: I believe that would be correct